# PHP 7.4 - Windows - high CPU when a function with large parameter has exception

Tags: php

I am working at a company with two Windows servers. I have one machine that was just upgraded to PHP 7.4.33 and the other one is still on 7.3.x.

The machine with the more updated PHP started experiencing high CPU usage, seen on the PHP fastCGI process. I was able to trace down the issue and make a minimal case to replicate it, but I can't explain it.

In short, I have a PHP file:

```
function errorCausingFunction($x=null){
        try{
                throw new Exception("error");
        }
        catch(Exception $e){
                echo "inside Exception";
        }
}

$x="abcdefg";
errorCausingFunction();     // test1
errorCausingFunction($x);   // test2
```

If I run this, `errorCausingFunction()` obviously gets called twice, once without the argument ("test1"), and once with ("test2"). The function handles the exception via `catch()`, and there's no further display or bubbling up of the exception. On both PHP 7.3.x and 7.4.33, it runs at approximately the same speed.

Now, if $x is instantiated to something much larger - let's say a very large, multi-megabyte-size object reference (very common on this application), or even, say, a very large multidimensional array unserialized from a file, PHP 7.4.33 bogs down **on the second function call ("test2") only**. In other words, **the size of the parameter into the "erroring" function causes it to slow down**. In this case, the slowdown can consume the entire CPU for 10-15+ minutes, or until I restart w3svc. The larger `$x`, the more the process consumes.

Reiterating some points:

- The slowdown only happens on 7.4.33.  PHP 7.3 runs fine in all scenarios.
- The exception is caught and handled with `catch()`. It is not getting logged anywhere (in other words, it's not like PHP is trying to write a huge stack trace to the php log file) nor bubbling up to PHP's error handling.
- While `zend.exception_ignore_args` is related in a sense, the setting does not make a difference here no matter what it's set to; there is no trace write occurring.
- The large argument is **never referenced in the function**  at all. Just the act of **passing** the argument causes the CPU to bog down when the Exception happens
- If no exception is thrown, i.e. if the function just outputs a message, everything is fine.
- The errorCausingFunction()  [sans argument, "test1"] can be called any number of times, and it's fine, regardless of the existence or size of `$x`.

I am out of ideas what to check. Everything else in the php.ini files is synched up and this is the only difference I've been able to narrow it down to. I'd appreciate any pointers.

Comment: This... feels like something you should be asking Zend about directly through a bug issue over on https://bugs.php.net/? I mean, certainly keep it open here to so you can post an answer if that yields one, but step one would be "file a bug" and then step five or six would be "post to Stackoverflow, your last resort when every other attempt at problem resolution has failed".

Comment: Do you have a machine running PHP 8.x ? What if the same code runs on PHP 8.x ?

Comment: Mike, do you have a reason to believe it's Zend? I only mentioned that particluar zend.exception_ignore_args to say that it's almost certainly *un*related (though might be the first thing to jump to mind for some). And while it certainly might be a bug...I feel like being at only 7.4.x means that I might be overlooking something that I haven't found on the bugs site.

Comment: Ken, i do not unfortunately.

Comment: I want to experience same platform, which version of windows you are using and are you using IIS or Apache?

Comment: It's Windows Server 2019 Standard with IIS

Comment: try to pass $x by ref. If $x is modified inside the func then it's may copy there.

Comment: Passing it and object references the way it currently does is valid, architecturally, so I'm not looking to re-engineer around the issue. Also, if $x represents an instance of a class (which it was in the original instance that prompted this question), it is passed by reference anyway. So, I think it's unrelated but I appreciate the eyes.

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be xDebug. In newer versions of xDebug, the setting "mode=develop" *should* only enable things like the "pretty" dump, and not do any tracing or other intense activities.

Unfortunately, though, it does apparently turn on some other unseen activity, even if all other setting are explicitly disabled. So we had to change xDebug to mode=off. If we want pretty dump, we have to call the xdebug_var_dump() function directly; it won't override the PHP var_dump() with mode=off.